# Yarn killing container running beyond virtual memory limits

Tags: linux, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to run a single-node hadoop cluster on a Raspberry Pi 3. I can run `hdfs dfs -ls /`, so I know that at least hdfs is up, but when I run the sample wordcount job as a smoke test to see if the cluster is working properly, I get the following error: `Container ... is running beyond virtual memory limits. Current usage: 33.8 MB of 255 MB physical memory used; 1.1 GB of 537.6 MB virtual memory used. Killing container.`
My configs are as follows:

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<property>  
<name>dfs.replication</name>  
<value>1</value>  
</property>
```

mapred-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>256</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx210m</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>256</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx210m</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
    <value>256</value>
  </property>
```

yarn-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
    <value>4</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>768</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>128</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>768</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
    <value>4</value>
  </property>
```

core-site.xml:

```
<property>  
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
</property>  
<property>  
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/hdfs/tmp</value>
</property>
```

The Raspberry Pi has CPU: 4× ARM Cortex-A53, and RAM: 1GB

In case it's helpful, my configs and setup are exactly the same as described in this blog post: https://web.archive.org/web/20170221231927/http://www.becausewecangeek.com/building-a-raspberry-pi-hadoop-cluster-part-1/

Comment: The hadoop daemon opts is some Java flag external to the yarn container sizes. The namenode and datanode are also Java processes taking up memory, and both default to 1g

Comment: @cricket_007 based on your comment, I found this site which seems to provide more info related to what you said about Java processes defaulting to 1GB: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-11-x/topics/admin_nn_memory_config.html. I changed `HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=1024` to `HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=500` in hadoop-env.sh, but got the same error as before. Am I changing the right environment variable, or are there others I should change as well?

Comment: That's the one. In the middle of this page about environment variables is where you can read the others. http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html Anyways, I really wouldn't even try to use raspberry pi to do any heavy Java processing like that. Sure, you can install Hadoop and get a datanode+namenode working, but YARN on top of that will not be happy.